# Second order sufficiency test for multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

**Question**: Suppose $f$ is a $\mathcal{C}^2$ function and $x^*$ is a point of its domain at which $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d \geq 0$ and ${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d > 0$ for every non-zero feasible direction. Is $x^*$ necessarily a local minimum?

Basically the question is asking whether the above two conditions are sufficient.

---

**My work so far:** If $\exists $ a feasible direction $d\in \mathbb{R}^n$ at $x^*$ such that $ \nabla f(x^*)d<0 $ then $\exists \epsilon >0 $ such that for $|\alpha| < \epsilon$ we have $ x(\alpha) = x^* + \alpha d \in D $. Then,

$$ f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) = f\left( {{x^*}} \right) + \nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right) - {x^*}} \right) + o\left( \alpha  \right)$$

$$ f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) = f\left( {{x^*}} \right) + \alpha \nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d + o\left( \alpha  \right) $$
where for small $\alpha$

$$ \alpha \nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d + o\left( \alpha  \right) < 0$$
since $\alpha \geq 0 $ and $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d < 0$. This implies $f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) - f\left( {{x^*}} \right) < 0$ contradicting that $x^*$ is a minimum. 
Now I claim if $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d = 0$ then, 
$${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d \geq 0$$
To see why note, 
$$f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) = f\left( {{x^*}} \right) + \nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right) - {x^*}} \right) + \frac{1}{2}{\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right) - {x^*}} \right)^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right) - {x^*}} \right) + o\left( {{\alpha ^2}} \right) $$
which simplifies to
$$f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) - f\left( {{x^*}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}{\alpha ^2}{d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d + o\left( {{\alpha ^2}} \right)$$

Note that $f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) - f\left( {{x^*}} \right) < 0$ for small $\alpha$ if ${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d < 0 $ which would contradict that $x^*$ is a minimum. Hence we must have $${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d \geq 0$$
**Claim**:If $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d > 0$ and ${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d > 0$ then $x^*$ is a necessarily local minimum. To see why, note that:
$$f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) = f\left( {{x^*}} \right) + \nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right) - {x^*}} \right) + \frac{1}{2}{\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right) - {x^*}} \right)^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right) - {x^*}} \right) + o\left( {{\alpha ^2}} \right)$$
simplifies to, 
$$f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) = f\left( {{x^*}} \right) + \alpha \nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d + \frac{1}{2}{\alpha ^2}{d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d + o\left( {{\alpha ^2}} \right)$$
$$ \Rightarrow f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) - f\left( {{x^*}} \right) = \alpha \nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d + \frac{1}{2}{\alpha ^2}{d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d + o\left( {{\alpha ^2}} \right) $$
We have $\alpha>0$ by definition of feasible direction. Moreovoer  $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d > 0$ and  ${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d > 0$ and since these two terms dominate, we always have $f\left( {x\left( \alpha  \right)} \right) - f\left( {{x^*}} \right) > 0$. Since $d$ is an arbitrary feasible direction, we see that moving away from $x^*$ only increases the value of $f$ which implies that $x^*$ is indeed the minimum. We can relax the condition $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d > 0$ to $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d \geq 0$ and the above will still hold. To see why ${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d > 0$ guarantees sufficiency note that if we only require ${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d \geq 0$ the $o\left(\alpha^2\right) $ term could make the LHS $<0$ when both $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d = 0$ and ${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d = 0$. However for the case when only $\nabla f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d \geq 0$ and ${d^T}{\nabla ^2}f\left( {{x^*}} \right)d > 0$ the whole term still remains positive. Hence the conditions are sufficient.

---

Apparently this proof is wrong and the two conditions in the question are **not** sufficient conditions. It has something to do with non-convex domains where a "nonlinear motion" may take you to a minimum. But I am having trouble wrapping my head around this. Does anyone know of a counter-example or a proof that the above are not sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of feasible directions can be $\{0\}$: Let $f(x) = - x_1^2 -x_2^2$.
Consider the feasible set 
$$
D=\{ x: x_1^2\le x_2\le 2x_1^2\}.
$$
Then $\nabla f(0)=0$ and there are no non-zero feasible directions at $x=0$, so your conditions are satisfied. But clearly, the origin is a local maximum of $f$, not a minimum.

Comment: I do not quite see that there are "no non-zero feasible directions" -- may you elaborate? What if $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @clocktower there was a typo in the definition of $D$

Comment: Thank you. One last question: can you state anything about how you know the conditions are satisfied? Are they vacuously satisfied in this case?

Comment: Yes: $d^T\nabla^2 f(0)d>0$ for all non-zero feasible direction $d$ - there is no such $d$.